# For a DIV with scrollbars, is it possible to make that div scroll all the way to the bottom, using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you do that using JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manipulating the scrollHeight:

http://kisdigital.wordpress.com/2009/11/12/using-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div/

```
$("#myDiv").attr({ scrollTop: $("#myDiv").attr("scrollHeight") });
```

Or if you want it animated:

```
$("#myDiv").animate({ scrollTop: $("#myDiv").attr("scrollHeight") }, 3000);
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this exact solution ... Well not exact. http://jsfiddle.net/Apr7W/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the jQuery ScrollTo pluging

`$('div').scrollTo(...);//all divs`

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html